# Better way to hide string and still function?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

Is there a better way to hide or encrypt the *username* string on append/setText and still function (send notification to username).

For now I can use spannable (transparent) or change the color of the string in java, but this is messy.

```
String username = l.getFromUserUsername();
String comment = chatText.getText().toString();
chatText.append("@" + username + " ");
```

Thanks

Update:
Encrypting the username string

```
compile 'com.github.simbiose:Encryption:2.0.1'

Encryption encryption = Encryption.getDefault("Key", "Salt", new byte[16]);
String username = encryption.encryptOrNull(l.getFromUserUsername());

chatText.append("@" + username + " ");
```

I can encrypt the username string in EditText, but the user doesn't receive the notification after sending. The user can only receive the notification when the username is not encrypted (@demouser).

Comment: Can you describe a bit more what you're trying to accomplish? I want to help but I'm really not sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: Sure, this is for replying to a user in a chatroom or in a comment section. The "@" + username + " " is added to the editText when a user taps the chat/comment of another user. For the other user to get a notification, the "@" + username string must be in the editText. What I'm trying to do is hide this string but still send the notification to the user. I'm not sure if this is possible, but any help is appreciated, thanks.